C# Playwright - Unable to add requests to datagrid with method request.AllHeadersAsync()
I am working on building an HTTP traffic interceptor using Playwright in C#. I am able to capture requests and add them to a datagrid using the following line of code of OnRequest method of BrowserService.cs:
var allHeaders = request.Headers;

However, this line of code only returns a limited set of headers. I tried using the following method to get all headers, but it prevents me from adding requests to the datagrid:
var allHeaders = await request.AllHeadersAsync();

Can you please help me fix this code so that I can capture all headers using AllHeadersAsync() and add the requests to the datagrid?
Below is code
BrowserService.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Playwright;

namespace TrafficInterceptorLibrary
{ 
public class BrowserService
{
    private IBrowser? _browser;
    private IPage? _page;
    private readonly Dictionary<IRequest, HttpRequestData> _requestDataMap = new();

    // Event to notify when a document request is captured
    public event Action<HttpRequestData>? OnDocumentRequestCaptured;

    public async Task StartBrowserAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
            _browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync(new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions { Headless = false });
            _page = await _browser.NewPageAsync();

            // Subscribe to request and response events
            _page.Request += OnRequest;
            _page.Response += OnResponse;

            // Optionally, you could open a blank page or a specific home page
            await _page.GotoAsync("about:blank");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Page loaded and events subscribed.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Error initializing browser: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    private async void OnRequest(object sender, IRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            // Only capture document requests
            if (request.ResourceType == "document")
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Request captured: {request.Url}");

                // Fetch the headers asynchronously
                var allHeaders = await request.AllHeadersAsync();

                // Debugging to check fetched headers
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Headers fetched asynchronously:");
                foreach (var header in allHeaders)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{header.Key}: {header.Value}");
                }

                var requestData = new HttpRequestData
                {
                    Method = request.Method,
                    Url = request.Url,
                    Domain = new Uri(request.Url).Host,
                    Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    Headers = allHeaders // Store the headers here
                };

                // Map the request to its data
                _requestDataMap[request] = requestData;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Error in OnRequest: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    private async void OnResponse(object sender, IResponse response)
    {
        try
        {
            if (response.Request.ResourceType == "document" && _requestDataMap.TryGetValue(response.Request, out var requestData))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Response received for: {response.Request.Url}");

                requestData.ResponseStatusCode = response.Status;
                requestData.ResponseStatusMessage = response.StatusText;
                requestData.BodySize = await GetResponseBodySize(response);

                // Debugging before invoking the event
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Triggering OnDocumentRequestCaptured event");

                // Trigger the event
                OnDocumentRequestCaptured?.Invoke(requestData);

                // Optionally, remove the entry from the map if it's no longer needed
                _requestDataMap.Remove(response.Request);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Error in OnResponse: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    private async Task<long> GetResponseBodySize(IResponse response)
    {
        long size = 0;
        try
        {
            var bodyBytes = await response.BodyAsync();
            size = bodyBytes.Length; // Size in bytes
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle exceptions
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Error reading response body: {ex.Message}");
        }

        return size;
    }

    private long GetRequestSize(IRequest request)
    {
        // Implement a way to get request size if needed
        // As there is no direct way to get the request size in Playwright,
        // you might need to calculate or estimate it.
        return 0;
    }

    public async Task StopBrowserAsync()
    {
        if (_browser != null)
        {
            await _browser.CloseAsync();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Browser closed.");
        }
    }
}

public class HttpRequestData
{
    public string Url { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Method { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int ResponseStatusCode { get; set; }
    public string ResponseStatusMessage { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public long HeaderSize { get; set; }
    public long BodySize { get; set; }
    public long RequestSize { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Headers { get; set; } = new();
    public string Domain { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
}

Form1.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using TrafficInterceptorLibrary;
using Timer = System.Windows.Forms.Timer;

namespace TrafficInterceptorUI
{
public partial class frmDetails : Form
{
    private readonly BrowserService _browserService;

    public frmDetails()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _browserService = new BrowserService();
        if (_browserService != null)
        {
            _browserService.OnDocumentRequestCaptured += OnDocumentRequestCaptured;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Event subscribed successfully inside frmDetails."); // Check if this is hit
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("BrowserService is null during event subscription.");
        }
    }

    private async void iconButton1_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Start the browser and capture traffic
        await Task.Delay(1000); // Delay to ensure form is fully loaded
        await _browserService.StartBrowserAsync();
    }

    private void OnDocumentRequestCaptured(HttpRequestData requestData)
    {
        // Debugging to check if method is called
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Captured request: {requestData.Url}");

        // Debugging to check fetched headers
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Headers fetched asynchronously:");
        foreach (var header in requestData.Headers)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{header.Key}: {header.Value}");
        }

        // Ensure that the UI update happens on the main thread
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new Action(() => AddRequestToGrid(requestData)));
        }
        else
        {
            AddRequestToGrid(requestData);
        }
    }

    private void AddRequestToGrid(HttpRequestData requestData)
    {
        // Debugging to check if adding to grid
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Adding to grid: {requestData.Url}");

        var row = new DataGridViewRow();
        row.CreateCells(dgvTrafficHistory);

        // Add data to the grid
        row.SetValues(false, requestData.Method, requestData.Url, requestData.Domain, requestData.Timestamp);
        row.Tag = requestData;

        dgvTrafficHistory.Rows.Add(row);

        // Debugging to confirm row was added
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Rows in grid: {dgvTrafficHistory.Rows.Count}");
    }

    private void dgvTrafficHistory_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvTrafficHistory.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            var selectedRow = dgvTrafficHistory.SelectedRows[0];
            var requestData = selectedRow.Tag as HttpRequestData;
            if (requestData != null)
            {
                UpdateDetails(requestData);
            }
        }
    }

    private void UpdateDetails(HttpRequestData requestData)
    {
        // Clear previous data
        lvGeneralInfo.Items.Clear();
        lvRequestHeaders.Items.Clear();

        // Populate General section
        lvGeneralInfo.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { "URL", requestData.Url }));
        lvGeneralInfo.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { "Method", requestData.Method }));
        lvGeneralInfo.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { "Status Code", $"{requestData.ResponseStatusCode} {requestData.ResponseStatusMessage}" }));
        lvGeneralInfo.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { "Request Headers Size", $"{requestData.HeaderSize} B" }));
        lvGeneralInfo.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { "Request Body Size", $"{requestData.BodySize} B" }));
        lvGeneralInfo.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { "Timestamp", requestData.Timestamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff") }));

        // Debugging headers
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Headers:");

        foreach (var header in requestData.Headers)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{header.Key}: {header.Value}");
        }

        // Populate Request Headers section
        foreach (var header in requestData.Headers)
        {
            var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(header.Key);
            listViewItem.SubItems.Add(header.Value);
            lvRequestHeaders.Items.Add(listViewItem);
        }
    }

    private void frmDetails_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Optionally, you can initialize your form or start any necessary timers here.
    }
}
}

